# converting strings of backslash character to backslash character

Tags: c++, string, backslash, string-conversion

Is there an easy what to convert a string of a backslash character into the  back slash character itself?

for example how would i accomplish something like this:

```
string newline = "\\n";
char n = somefunction(newline); // n == '\n'
cout << newline << n << "a new line";


/*output:
\n
a new line
*/
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but it isn't very tricky to write it yourself.

Comment: What should `somefunction` return if it gets any other string than `"\\n"`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your string only has the code that you want to convert:

```
char somefunction(std::string code)
{
   if ( code.length() != 2 )
       return /* your error code here */

   if ( code[0] != '\\' )
       return /* your error code here */

   switch(code[1]) {
       case 'n' : return '\n';
       case 't' : return '\t';
       case 'r' : return '\r';
   }
   return /* your error code here */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (auto it = newline.begin(); it != newline.end(); ++it) {
  if ((*it) == '\\')
    newline.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Too simplistic, you are only handling the escape for the escape-character itself.

Comment: that code would turn "\\n" into "n" instead of "\n"

Comment: You're using invalidated iterators.